# geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim(), is not working angular

Tags: leaflet, angular10, leaflet-routing-machine

i try it many time but no resullt
the problem that i want to dispaly depart address and destination address but i found thar erreur

```
 this.routing = L.Routing.control({
      waypoints: [
       ...
      ],
      language: 'fr',
      showAlternatives: true,
      routeWhileDragging: true,
      reverseWaypoints: true,
      routeDragInterval: 0,
      autoRoute: true,
      **geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim(),**
      
      altLineOptions: {
        styles: [
          {color: 'black', opacity: 0.1, weight: 11},
          {color: 'white', opacity: 0.25, weight: 9},
          {color: 'blue', opacity: 0.25, weight: 3}
        ]
      },
      lineOptions: {
        styles: [
          {color: 'black', opacity: 0.3, weight: 11},
          {color: 'white', opacity: 0.9, weight: 9},
          {color: 'red', opacity: 1, weight: 3}
        ]
      },
        }
      }
    }).addTo(map);

    this.map = map;
```

image of the erreur https://i.stack.imgur.com/17oP2.png

this is my erreur :

> Blockquote`core.js:4442 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nominatim' of undefined at AppComponent.ngOnInit (app.component.ts:60) at callHook (core.js:3281) .....`

Comment: Beware the upper/lowercase "n" in "nominatim".

Comment: this propose do not solve the issue :(